# Adding holiday eves on a dateframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe, date, timestamp

I have the following dataframe in Python:
The date column is in TimeStamp format.

| date | holiday_type | name | other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | Holiday | Holiday 1 | UK |
| 2022-01-02 00:00:00 | Holiday | Holiday 2 | UK |
| 2022-03-08 00:00:00 | Holiday | Holiday 3 | UK |
| 2022-04-12 00:00:00 | Holiday | Holiday 4 | UK |

I want to add new rows for records from the day before those specified dates. The resulting dataframe will look like this:

| date | holiday_type | name | other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-31 00:00:00 | Pre Holiday | (Pre) Holiday 1 | UK |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | Holiday | Holiday 1 | UK |
| 2022-01-02 00:00:00 | Holiday | Holiday 2 | UK |
| 2022-03-07 00:00:00 | Pre Holiday | (Pre) Holiday 3 | UK |
| 2022-03-08 00:00:00 | Holiday | Holiday 3 | UK |
| 2022-04-11 00:00:00 | Pre Holiday | (Pre) Holiday 4 | UK |
| 2022-04-12 00:00:00 | Holiday | Holiday 4 | UK |

Exceptions are that if the previous day is already a holiday, the pre-holiday is not added.

I hope you can help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a more efficient way to do this, but here's how I did it.

I created a dataframe that offset your dates by a day. Then added the suffix `'(Pre) '` and changed the `holiday_type` to `'Pre Holiday'`. I then appended it to the original dataframe, sorted, and dropped duplicate dates, keeping the last entry.

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['date','holiday_type','name','other']
data = [['2022-01-01 00:00:00', 'Holiday',  'Holiday 1',    'UK'],
['2022-01-02 00:00:00', 'Holiday',  'Holiday 2',    'UK'],
['2022-03-08 00:00:00', 'Holiday',  'Holiday 3',    'UK'],
['2022-04-12 00:00:00', 'Holiday',  'Holiday 4',    'UK']]



df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df_yesterday = df[df['holiday_type'] == 'Holiday']
df_yesterday['date']  = df_yesterday['date'] + pd.offsets.Day(-1)
df_yesterday['holiday_type'] = 'Pre Holiday'
df_yesterday['name'] = '(Pre) ' + df_yesterday['name']

df = pd.concat([df, df_yesterday]).sort_values(['date', 'holiday_type'], ascending=[True, False]).reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.drop_duplicates(['date'], keep='last').reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
        date holiday_type             name other
0 2021-12-31  Pre Holiday  (Pre) Holiday 1    UK
1 2022-01-01      Holiday        Holiday 1    UK
2 2022-01-02      Holiday        Holiday 2    UK
3 2022-03-07  Pre Holiday  (Pre) Holiday 3    UK
4 2022-03-08      Holiday        Holiday 3    UK
5 2022-04-11  Pre Holiday  (Pre) Holiday 4    UK
6 2022-04-12      Holiday        Holiday 4    UK
```